# How to use both stacknavigator and tabnavigator together?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

Currently I have redux and stacknavigator and I wanted to implement a bottom tab navigator. With this I found out about tabnavigator and I am not sure how to implement both of them. This is my current App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { YellowBox } from 'react-native';
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings(['Warning: isMounted(...) is deprecated', 'Module RCTImageLoader']);

import store from './store'; //Import the store

import Home from './components/home' //Import the component file
import Cart from './components/cart';
import SearchResults from './components/searchResults';

export default class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Provider store={store}>
                <Root />
            </Provider>
        );
    }
}


const Root = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home: {
      screen: Home
    },
    Cart:{
      screen: Cart
    },
    SearchResults:{
      screen: SearchResults
    }
  }, 
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  }
);
```

I need to use the stacknavigator to trigger my Search button and pass data from it and at the same time I am using redux. In this case, is it possible for me to have a bottom tab navigator as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Create different stack using StackNavigator and then add those stacks in tabNavigator.

Normally each stack should belongs to any tab. Like if you have users stack and user detail screen but only users list tab, then user details screen will highlight user list tab also. Below code not related to your code, but might give you idea.

```
const homeStack = createStackNavigator({
  Home: { 
    screen: Home, 
    navigationOptions:{
      title  : "Home",
      ...headerStyle
    }
  },
  AboutUs: {  
    screen: AboutUs, 
    navigationOptions:{
      title  : "About Us",
      ...headerStyle
    }
  },
})

const pickerStack = createStackNavigator({ 
  UsersList: { 
    screen: UsersList, 
    navigationOptions:{
      title  : "Users List",
      ...headerStyle
    }
  },
  UsersDetails: {
    screen: UsersDetails, 
    navigationOptions:{
      title  : "Users Details",
      ...headerStyle
    }
  },
  PickerSignup: {
    screen: PickerSignup, 
    navigationOptions:{
      title  : "Signup as a Picker",
      ...headerStyle
    }
  }  
});

const App = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Home: homeStack,   
  Users: pickerStack
},    
{ 
  initialRouteName : "Home", 
  navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
    tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
      const { routeName } = navigation.state;
      let iconName;
      let routeIconMapping = {
        'Home' : 'home',
        'Users':'account-multiple',
        'Food':'food'
      }
      iconName = (routeName && routeIconMapping[routeName]) ? routeIconMapping[routeName] : 'home';
      return <MatIcon name={iconName} size={25} color={tintColor} />;
    },
  }), 
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: 'tomato',
    inactiveTintColor: 'gray',
    activeBackgroundColor: 'white'
  },
}
);
```

Comment: Welcome. Glad it helps